# Azure Logic App: Take API JSON input and map values to keys within another JSON Object

Tags: json, azure, logic

I am making an API call that returns JSON in the beneath format:

```
{
    "query_status": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "41",
            "ioc": "gaga.com",
            "threat_type": "botnet_cc",
            "threat_type_desc": "Indicator that identifies a botnet command&control server (C&C)",
            "ioc_type": "domain",
        },
        [...]
}
```

I am looking for a solution whereby I can take these values and append them to a table in Azure. I need to assign some these values to the beneath:

```
{
  "emailSenderName": "String",
  "emailSourceDomain": "String",
  "emailSourceIpAddress": "String",
  "emailSubject": "String",
  "emailXMailer": "String",
  "expirationDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "externalId": "String",
  "fileCompileDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "fileCreatedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "fileHashType": "string",
  "fileHashValue": "String",
  "fileMutexName": "String",
  "fileName": "String",
  "filePacker": "String",
  "filePath": "String",
  "fileSize": 1024,
  "fileType": "String",
  "id": "String (identifier)",
  "ingestedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "isActive": true,
  "killChain": ["String"],
}
```

The desired output is to create the object shown on this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tiindicator-submittiindicators?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

What is the best way to do this? After scanning through the MS documentation I haven't found anything that helps. Essentially what I'd like to do is change the keys.

Comment: Your API response has only 5 fields in the response. Where are you planning to source the remaining fields of your final outcome? What do you mean by append to a table in Azure? Do you mean append it to a JSON message? You will need a parse json step to fetch the individual fields from the response and then you can try creating a json variable using the dynamic content(set variable or compose)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a compose action in the logic app like in this example:
[image]